# in Node.js event loop - will callbacks to say i/o events say 'new HTTP request received' be executed in the 'I/O Callbacks' phase OR 'Poll' phase

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I see that Event loop typically phases through the following cycle in each iteration: Timers -> I/O Callbacks -> idle -> Poll -> Check -> Close
as per the official Node.js docs https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ .

Now it also says 'I/O Callbacks' phase executes callbacks for some system operations such as types of TCP errors' for example typical operations like TCP connection errors.

and in the 'Poll' phase - it says 'retrieve new I/O events' . like incoming connections , data, etc

I am confused. in which phase are I/O events (callback handlers) like 'new HTTP Request received', 'data received from database per previous query' are executed?

Comment: Note that from a regular user point of view - this shouldn't typically concern you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Generally

Generally, you shouldn't care about these phases. Even the distinction between a microtask (like nextTick) and a macrotask (like setImmediate) is not very important for every day NodeJS developers. That article is an in depth look at how Node handles thing *internally*.

All a user typically has to care about is that when they register a request - the callback they provide will *eventually* be called at *some later time in the future* which is typically *fast enough* as long as they don't "block the event loop" by doing a lot of synchronous CPU bound work on the Node process.

#### Your specific question

> in which phase are I/O events (callback handlers) like 'new HTTP Request received', 'data received from database per previous query' are executed?

They are executed in the poll phase:

> If the poll queue is not empty, the event loop will iterate through its queue of callbacks executing them synchronously until either the queue has been exhausted, or the system-dependent hard limit is reached.

Note that the poll phase is not the only place where I/O callbacks might be executed. The (somewhat poorly named) `I/O callbacks` phase is also in charge of some callbacks. This is due to how libuv works and should be transparent in your code. In addition - some libraries (like DB libraries) might do their own scheduling and run callback code inside a timer (in the timers phase) - and some asynchronous callbacks like close callbacks run in their own phase.

Comment: No. This is wrong. They are not executed in the poll phase. The poll phase actually blocks until the OS sends an event to the interpreter. They are executed in the callback phase. In the OP's question it looks like node.js docs split the callback phase into two parts, the timer phase and the I/O callback phase. That's just to clarify that timers are processed before other callbacks.

Comment: The description you've given `if the poll queue is not empty` IS the callback phase.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing to be confused about. All async callbacks are executed in the callback phase. It is one of the only two places where the interpreter execute javascript: when the script starts and in the callback phase.

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question at all - there are more than 2 phases.

Comment: If you are not the one who implement Node.js, at least you should read the doc careful, from https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ , I can see it is 'poll phase'

Comment: @Guigui Read the doc carefully. In the poll phase it says if the poll queue is not empty which is the callback phase. More specifically read the code, not just the docs. Code cannot be executed in the poll phase because in the poll phase the process sleeps (nothing is executed until the OS interrupts us with an event)